# read() and write() to sockets returning corrupted values

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, solaris

I have tried writing to a socket using `write()` command. The data I need to write is of structure type and it contains both `char` and `int` datatype values. But when I write the data to the server socket, the value of the `int` variable is getting corrupted. I am receiving a value as `16777216` always.

I am writing from a `Solaris` machine to a `Linux` machine. `Solaris` is a 32 bit machine and `Linux` is a 64 bit machine. Do this have any impact on my problem.

I used `htonl`/`ntohl` and vice versa for passing the `int`eger values from and to the server. But how can I use this if I am writing the whole structure type into the socket? Can anyone help me to sort this out?

```
PCHAR data = NULL;
int size = sizeof(WSMsg);
int retry = 10;
data = new char [sizeof(WSMsg)];
memcpy(data, msg, sizeof(WSMsg));
int n = write(fd, &data[0], size);
```

This is my code part. Here `WSMsg` is of structure type and has `int` and `char` type values.

I am writing a particular row from the database table which contains number, `char` type values. And I am writing different rows of different tables like this. So if I need to use `htonl`/`ntohl` then I need to convert all of these numbers to network bytes. As I have 20 or more tables and its structures which is having integer type values, it will be a time consuming job for me to convert all of these and send across.

Comment: Why not call `write` with the structure directly? I.e. `write(fd, msg, sizeof(WSMsg))`

Comment: I can do that but my integer values is getting corrupted when I receive the data at the other end. Everything is working fine if I transfer the data from Solaris to Solaris or from Linux to Linux. The problem arises when I am writing from Solaris to Linux or vice versa.

Comment: Well "Solaris" usually means "SPARC" which is big-endian, whereas "Linux" usually means "x86 or ARM". So writing a full structure causing corruption wouldn't be surprising.

Comment: @Damon So is there any way to sort this out??

Comment: Using `htonl/ntohl` correctly should work, but you must obviously do that for every single member of the structure much like serializing,  and "unserialize" the structure on the other side.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are having problems with byte-order. There are a couple of different ways to solve this: One is to look into [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), i.e. convert the structures you send to a format which is independent of byte-order issues; Another solution is to create a copy of your structure, and use e.g. `htons`/`htonl` where needed:

```
WSMsg temp = *msg;
temp.someShortField = htons(temp.someShortField);
// etc.
```

Then of course do the opposite on the receiving side.